# Is VBA unable to replace an entire paragraph into Word Document?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am using VBA to replace a variable [Z] in WordDocument, using a cell (Y) in Excelsheet

When I run the program, the variable [Z] in worddocument is replaced, but it becomes blank. The values in cell (Y) was not registered in the word document.

Why the Cell Y contents are unable to be replaced into the word document?

Contents of Cell Y is below...
Cell (Y):

1. To do the following:

   1.1. AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
   (AAA)

   1.2. BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
   (AAA)

   1.3. CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
   (AAA)
2. To do the following:

   2.1. DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
   (AAA)

   2.2. EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
   (AAA)
3. To do the following:

   3.1. FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
   (AAA)

```
Dim WordApp As Object
Dim WordDoc As Object 
Dim FileName As String 
Dim GenFormat As String
Dim Z As String

Dim WordContent As Word.Range

Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=Formloc, ReadOnly:=False)

GenFormat = "General"

Z = Cells(9, 4).Value
        With WordDoc.Content.Find
        .Text = "[Z]"
        .Replacement.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Z, GenFormat)
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With

WordDoc.Close
WordApp.Quit      
Set WordApp = Nothing
Set WordDoc = Nothing
```

Comment: Can't be sure but when your cell content is above 255 characters, Application.WorkSheetFunction.Text(Z,GenFormat) will cause an error. AFAICS just using the value you assigned to Z should work, i.e. using .Replacement.Text = Z . Does that also fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify a replacement format that way. Hence, you can use:

```
Z = Cells(9, 4).Text
...
.Replacement.Text = Z
```

to replace just the text content.

If you need to replace using the character formatting of the cell or its contents, you could use something like:

```
Cells(9, 4).Copy
    With WordDoc.Range
      With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "[Z]"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
      End With
      Do While .Find.Execute
        .PasteAndFormat wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      Loop
    End With
```